PowerPoint on macOS - equation substitutions don't work
I'm using PowerPoint on macOS, and the equation substitutions don't work anymore:

Insert -> Equation
In the equation: type \alpha, type space, nothing happens. Previously, this would replace \alpha with α.

What works:

Parenthesis. I.e., if I type (), and then type space, it will scale the parenthesis to match the size of what's inside them
Superscripts ^ and subscript _
None of the commands starting with \ work.

What I tried:

Reinstall PowerPoint
Delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.PowerPoint.plist

One remotely possible suspect: I recently changed Preferences -> Autocorrect. There, I unselected "Capitalize first letter of sentences" and "Capitalize names of days". I don't know if this is the reason, but this is simply the only change I made in settings. I reverted this change, didn't help (and I also deleted the file outlined above).

What actually worked was deleting file ~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office. It seems the file you need to delete might depend on the Office version.
Changing the Autocorrect options was indeed the issue.
